# Split wide screen monitor in 2 fake screens for the system

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, widescreen

I want to buy a wide screen (50 inch) but i want to know if i can split the screen into 2/3 fake screen (for windows / linux or even macos) (with software or hardware).
The first and third fake screen will have each 1/4 and the second (middle screen) will have 2/4 of the total monitor screen.

EDIT:
Like this image:
(I've edited an image of wide screen monitor that use Win10)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4TRm.jpg

To be more precise, that just for one pc, no other source.
I use 3 OS on my pc (depend on my need) so the software must be working on those three.

Comment: Please narrow your post to a single question. Right now you're asking about multiple operating systems and multiple possible setups. This means that it will be difficult for a single answer to suffice, and SuperUser is all about specific questions with a single good answer. Also, while you've given us an image showing what you want it to look like, what have you actually done/researched/learned/tried so far to do this yourself?

Comment: @s0me1ne , when you say "I use 3 OS on my PC" , do you mean that you are multi-booting so that only one OS is chosen on boot?  Or are you using virtualization?  You say there is just one PC, so you're not using Remote software.

Comment: I'm multi-booting (Hackintosh macos, linux and windows). All is local, no remote.

Answer (score 0):

The closest possible for under $5,000 is a [4 in 1 multiviewer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0732XM1Q8).

Answer (score 0):

- **If you are talking about combining outputs from different sources**, one thing to think about is the aspect ratio of the component screens.  Screens are rectangular, with a small range of aspect ratio.  If you divide the screen real estate into blocks that are standard resolutions, output will be sharp and normal.  So things like dividing in half vertically and horizontally to make 4 screens works well.

  If you start making arbitrary divisions, like you describe, the pieces won't be standard resolutions.  So you are likely to get distortion when stretching things to fit a different aspect ratio, and interpolation that will degrade the sharpness and clarity.

  Dividing a screen into 4 is a common thing with surveillance cameras, so you can probably find something off-the-shelf to do that.
- **If you're talking about just simulating multiple monitors**, you should be able to just use windows or virtual desktops.  Those can be any arbitrary size and shape you want, and the content within them will still be native resolution.